# Isomorphisms of direct products of finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Suppose $G_1, G_2, H_1, H_2$ are finite abelian groups with $G_1 \times G_2 \cong H_1 \times H_2$, and $G_1 \cong H_1$. Prove that $G_2 \cong H_2$.

Since the groups are finite, the isomorphisms imply equal orders, so $|G_2| = |H_2|$. And by the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, $G_1 \times G_2$ must have the same prime-power cyclic group decomposition as $H_1 \times H_2$, and similarly, $G_1$ and $H_1$ have the same decomposition. I'm not entirely sure what to do from here. I feel like the fundamental theorem should get me most of the way there, I just don't know how to *say* it. Or should I try constructing the isomorphism from the two isomorphisms I've assumed? Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I were working this problem, I would try to construct an isomorphism from $G_1$ to $H_1$. (Disclaimer: I'm a neophyte to group theory and can only vaguely remember the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, so there definitely might be a shorter approach.)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is true for general finite groups by the Krull-Schmidt Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to construct an isomorphism from $G_1$ to $H_1$. Here are my thoughts along those lines:

There are homomorphisms from $G_2$ into $G_1 \times G_2$ and from $H_2$ into $H_1 \times H_2$. Along with the isomorphism from $G_1 \times G_2$ to $H_1 \times H_2$, can we construct an isomorphism from $G_2$ to $H_2$?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just drew out the diagram and that helped a lot. I'm pretty sure I've got it just by mapping
$$G_2 \to G_1 \times G_2 \to H_1 \times H_2 \times \to H_2$$
$$g_2 \mapsto (e, g_2) \mapsto (e, h_2) \mapsto (h_2)$$
I just want to verify that it's a function/isomorphism before I accept, I definitely appreciate the help though. I see how I use my other assumptions in making sure that this is an isomorphism, but I don't think I've used the fact that they're abelian anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a short exact sequence argument
$$
1\to G_1\to G_1\times G_2\to G_2\to 1\\
1\to H_1\to H_1\times H_2\to H_2\to 1.
$$
Pretend you have vertical lines between those things. You have isomorphisms at positions 1, 2, 3, and 5. Using the [five lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma), you should be able to prove that the last one is an isomorphism as well. This might be overkill though.

Comment: I see a stray ! that should probably be a 1.

Comment: Nah, it was the excited subgroup.

Comment: Does this work?  Do we know that the two given isomorphisms form a commutative diagram for the exact sequences above?

Comment: @Ted: This does not work: e.g. if $G_1 = H_1$, the first vertical map is the identity, but the second is $\varphi \times 1$ where $1 \ne \varphi \in \text{Aut}(G_1)$, then the diagram does not commute. Even more, there is no map $G_2 \to H_2$ to begin with (one must choose a section of the projection $G_1 \times G_2 \to G_2$)

Answer (score 1):

You are right about to use fundeamental theorem of abelian group. You need only consider the case that $G=G_1 \times G_2=H_1 \times H_2$ (Why?) Next, you can only consider that $G$ is a $p$-group (why?). Finally, since every abelian $p$-group has a uniquely decomposition in cyclic subgroups, you can get what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow you. It doesn't seem like $G = G_1 \times G_2 = H_1 \times H_2$ should necessarily be a $p$-group. All we've assumed about it is that it's the product of finite abelian groups, which doesn't seem like it should be enough to know that it's a $p$-group (although I'm certainly open to being wrong.) Wouldn't the conclusion that we can decompose it uniquely into cyclic subgroups hold without it being a $p$-group?

Comment: In general, th cyclic decomposition is not unique: $Z_6 =Z_3 \times Z_2$. But it is true for abelian $p$-group. Although in general, $G$ may be not a $p$-group. But we can cosider the subgroup consisting all the elements of order of power of $p$.